# Devexpress Gridview Data Row and Columns Value

Tags: c#, save, devexpress, rows, gridcontrol

Please refer to the simple table below.

I don't know how to save all data.

GRIDVIEW:

```
      COLUMN1| COLUMN2 | COLUMN3 | COLUMN4 | COLUMN |....
 ROW1        |  100    |   105   |   109   |   112  |
 ROW2        |   55    |    58   |    62   |    67  |
 ROW3        |   71    |    75   |    79   |    83  |
 ROW4        |  204    |   209   |   216   |   221  |
 ROW..
```

gridviewRowsColumns

[image: gridviewRowsColumns]

Notes:

- First column = stock code, (in tag property, contain ID)
- Columns COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3.... sales prices for stock.

Comment: where and how will you 'save' it? would you like to save it to external file like excel, word? or where ?

Comment: Can you past the code when you fill the GridView ?

Comment: What is the data source for your GridControl? Have you reviewed the [Posting Data to a Connected Database](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1082) documentation?

Comment: @Kagan -- you've been asked three great questions...  if you can answer all of these, I'll bet these good folks can help you out.